# How to use SSE Instruction set in C/Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, c, sse

I'm trying to make a Function that Sums 2 `CGVectors`.

This is my try:

Includes:

```
@import GLKit;
@import Foundations;


    // Defenition of CGVector
    struct CGVector {
        CGFloat dx;
        CGFloat dy;
    };

    typedef struct CGVector CGVector;

    inline CGVector CGVECADD(CGVector v1 , CGVector v2){
    #ifdef GLK_SSE3_INTRINSICS
        __m128d v;
        v = _mm_add_sd(*(__m128d *)&v1, *(__m128d *)&v2);

        return *(CGVector *)& v;
    #else
        return CGVectorMake(v1.dx + v2.dx, v1.dy + v2.dy);
    #endif
    }
```

Then I am trying to use it like

```
    CGVector v1, v2 , v3;
    v1 = CGVectorMake(2, 3);
    v2 = CGVectorMake(4, 4);;
    v3 = CGVECADD(v1, v2); //(6, 7) expected
    NSLog(@"V3 = (%lf, %lf)", v3.dx , v3.dy);
```

No compiler errors But what I got from logs is

> V3 = (6.000000, 3.000000)

I expected to have 6,7 :-)

What Have I done wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
CGVector v1, v2, v3;
v1 = CGVectorMake(2, 3);
v2 = CGVectorMake(4, 4);
v3 = CGVectorMake(v1.dx + v2.dx, v1.dy + v2.dy);
NSLog(@"V3 = (%f, %f)", v3.dx, v3.dy);
```

**Output**:

```
V3 = (6.000000, 7.000000)
```

Comment: But the Whole Idea is to make it with SSE2

Comment: It's unclear if you are trying this within an obj-c file or c. Maybe include that info and the includes, imports too... in other words the rest of the code. :)

Comment: Edited: The file is .m , but it contains only C functions

Comment: I have looked into the assembly generated with -O3 optimization -Of the simple (naive code that you provided)- its clearly uses SSE3 And I doubt I can manually beat it anyway.

Comment: From the assembly I saw that I should use '_mm_add_pd()' This actually gives the desired result, however generates more assembly lines (it actually copies the v1 and v2 into new _m128d and performs shuffling ), --- but it is already another question.

Comment: That is indeed the issue; so beyond changing what the function does I'd say use `_mm_add_pd`. It's unclear what the issue is with generating more assembly lines...

Comment: CGFloat defined as double in 64bit machines(I am supporting only64bit). the assembly is like 4 rows more 2 rows for copy and 2 more for shuffle  - Auto generated just doest it all neat just takes the CGVector as mm0 without copy and shuffle. I think I need to use some kind of '_mm_load_##' instead of just casting CGVector to _m128d which invokes an unwanted copy. I am new to this stuff it is my first try.

Comment: The `_mm_add_sd` operator adds the lower double-precision, floating-point values of a and b; the upper double-precision, floating-point value is passed through from a ( yes, weird huh? ) . `_mm_add_pd` simply adds the two double-precision, floating-point values of a and b.

Comment: Honestly I am really impressed that Apple compiler did a super great optimization for this. I also seen from another function that it even optimizes sqrt() from math.h to use SSE intrinsic. Seems like I have little to none bother with the code optimizations nowadays.